# ASP.NET why Gridview Paging on page 2 and the rest of it are disappear?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have so many list of ServerName in GridView, so I decide to add paging. The data show list result on page 1 but on page 2 and the rest of it is not display anything. I already have `OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewServer_PageIndexChanging"` in GridViewServer property. Please help! Here is c# code behind,

```
protected void GridViewServer_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewServer.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridViewServer.DataBind();
    }
```

A GridView binding function codes,

```
public void BindGridView()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn.Open();

        string sqlquery = ("SELECT * FROM tblServer");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adp.Fill(ds);

        GridViewServer.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        GridViewServer.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your GridView's datasource appropriately. You can't just call DataBind if the datasource isn't properly set. Basically what it amounts to is binding your GridView to null (which would have no page 2). I would recommend having a private method that is responsible for this process and whenever you need to bind you call that.

```
private void BindGridViewServer()
{
    GridViewServer.DataSource = GetYourData();  // This should get the data
    GridViewServer.DataBind();
}
```

Call this method from within your event with:

```
protected void GridViewServer_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewServer.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGridViewServer();
}
```

This could be made more extensible by passing in the GridView as a parameter, but you'd have to have other parameters as well to make sure the method retrieves the proper data.

Comment: I don't get it, what about GridViewServer_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)?

Comment: @StudentIT: I posted an edit that includes how to call this method.

Comment: so on GetYourData() part, how can I get data of what left for page 2 and the rest of it?

Comment: It's the same data you got for page 1. By changing the page index with `e.NewPageIndex` you're allowing the GridView to bind only to the subset of data that would appear on the expected page. My recommendation is that whereever in your code that you bind your GridView to see page 1, you use this private method. That provides consistency to your binding since you're always binding to the same data.

Comment: I just edit it that I already create a GridView Bind on page 1. What should I do with this?

Comment: @StudentIT I think what Joel Etherton is trying to say is that you need to rebind the data each time the page changes.  This is also true when the sort order changes.

Comment: @StudentIT: The answer to your last question is in my original answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very good tutorial (with sample code) on custom GridView paging. This makes the paging controls look like the familiar ones you see on a lot of search engines, forums, etc.

http://geekswithblogs.net/aghausman/archive/2009/05/18/custom-paging-in-grid-view.aspx

Comment: This is custom made paging. I don't want that

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? If it's 4.0, I don't believe you have to have code. Just put Allow_Paging="true" in your GridView and you're good to go

Comment: Also, if your GridView has AutoGenerateColumns="true", I don't believe you need any code regardless of the .Net version. Just put AllowPaging="true"

Answer (score 0):

You have to give datasource to GridViewServer every time on page index changed.
so the code would be like this

```
protected void GridViewServer_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewServer.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridViewServer.Datasource = MethodReturningDataTable();
    GridViewServer.DataBind();
}
```